Different posts (created with Wordpress post and with ACF post type) with same content,slug,category,published date. Only difference is appearance
We are a group of Newbies in using wordpress,3 months old!
Where did we go wrong and HELP!
PROBLEM:
Because we wanted to create a totally new appearance to all 100 posts that were published, we created another "Post" directory using ACF Post type in dashboard.
HOW?
We use Elements function in Kadence Pro to create a new post template. We copied exactly everything from the Wordpress Post into Field Group in ACF. Same content,same slug,same category,same published date.
PUBLISHED DAY!

we put everything from Wordpress "post" to Private status (we have not deleted them)
We have published the new appearance "post" (created using ACF)

OUTCOME:

Everything works fine with ACF posts EXCEPT we cannot EDIT.
Error message says " You attempted to edit an item that doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?"

We could however create  a new post, Quick edit, trash and view.
Strangely though, the old link in Facebook pulls up the new posts despite different link. Example oldlink: www.XYZ.com/slug name; New link: www.XYZ.com/ACF "Post" directory name/slug name

when we do a google search, the homepage comes up but subpages shows "Page NOT Found" in google page (it is still referring to old link- - we have informed Yoast and Google about Updates to Index)

HYPOTHESIS:
Problem 1.We now realise it could be slug conflict.
Problem 2. We need to clear cache in Siteground
OUR PROPOSED SOLUTION:
METHOD 1:
1.We will reuse the old posts from Wordpress which is in Private status now by changing to new appearance using Kadence Pro Elements and ACF.
2. clear the cache in siteground
QUESTION:
1.Will this solve the problem?
2. Will our viewership numbers in the old posts created using wordpress before be retained and continue running?
METHOD 2:

Use the existing ACF created posts and delete/ change slug name in Wordpress "posts"
clear the cache in siteground

QUESTION:
1.Will this solve the problem?
2. Is there anyway we can add our viewership numbers from the old posts
We are concerned with viewership numbers bcos we understand it has impact on SEO.
We hope this does not flood you with information, We thought as much info we could provide would point to the precise problem and correct solution. Our humble appeal to all generous experienced people out there to help us, please....
